# How do i output a single digit as a double digit in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I just started to play around with python and decided to make a random number generator for my lotto numbers and so far so good it works, and even got it to work in Tkinter.

But i can't seem to figure out where and how to format the output so that it displays some nicely formatted rows of lists.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Hugo

The script I got working so far in python 2.7

```
import random
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter as ttk


def f():
    my_list = []
    while len(my_list) < 6:
        new_number = random.randrange(45) + 1
        if new_number in my_list:
            continue
        my_list.append(new_number)
        winners = sorted(my_list)
        if len(my_list) == 6:
            return winners


def genereer(*args):
    x = int(getal.get())
    my_list2 = []
    if x < 11:
        while len(my_list2) < x:
            f()
            my_list2.append(f())
    for item in my_list2:
        ttk.Label(mainframe, text=item).grid(column=0, sticky=W)


root = Tk()
root.title("Lotto nummers generator.")

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root)
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

getal = StringVar()

ttk.Label(mainframe,
text="Hoeveel rijtjes will je spelen? (max 10)").grid(column=0, row=1,sticky=W)

getal_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=3, textvariable=getal)
getal_entry.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=W)

ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Genereer", command=genereer).grid(column=3,
row=1, sticky=W)

getal_entry.focus()
root.bind("<Return>", genereer)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do you need output "01" instead of "1"? if yes, you can use "%02d" format for your output. ttk.Label format object you output to text as "%s"

Comment: yes i wanted to output 01 or a preceding space doesn't really matter as long as it looks a little nicer. Thanks for your input I am gonna try and fool around with that to hopefully get it working. But so far in my first attempts not much luck yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shoud do apply following code:

```
for item in my_list2:
    text = map(lambda x: '%02d'%(x,), item)
    ttk.Label(mainframe, text=text).grid(column=0, sticky=W)
```

Comment: Thanks that made it work. Much appreciated am gonna try and figure out the how and why now. But it helps a lot to see a working example.

Answer (score 1):

I was never using TKinter, but I tried sth like that:

```
...

MAX_VALUE = 46
NUMS_PER_SAMPLE = 6
POOL = range(1, MAX_VALUE+1)


def f():
    return sorted(random.sample(POOL, NUMS_PER_SAMPLE))


def genereer(*args):
    x = int(getal.get())

    if x > 10:
        return

    for x in range(x):
        for i, item in enumerate(f()):
            ttk.Label(mainframe, text=item).grid(row=x+2, column=i, sticky=E)

...
```

It's not perfect, because it uses the same grid as initial label and button, but from that point you should be able to adjust it to your needs. I also simplified your code by taking advantage of standard library ([`random.sample`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) is your friend).

Comment: This is much better code in other parts, not in what question is about

Comment: I used grid to present results, so it (also) answers to the question, but I agree, I changed a lot instead of just focusing on answer.

Comment: Thanks for your input was also working on something with a for loop structure but started with the while loop and stubborn as I am I wanted that one to work first. But I am gonna dive into your suggestion to after I figure out the how and why from the other answer but much appreciated.

Comment: I was fooling around a bit with your suggestion and it solves another problem witch I was having with my script that it refreshes the output if I press the button or enter again. But after i do that for about ten times it does not seem to return any numbers under ten anymore. It does close down in a really cool looking way after that (u see random numbers disappear before it closes). But i guess that's an error but looks nice.